# Google Org Chart Striations

Tags: c#, .net, google-chrome, google-visualization

I am having problems with google charts displaying in Chrome. The issue is illustrated in the picture below.

[image: Striations in Google Org Chart]

The striations go across the entire chart area and I don't understand why. The striations do not show up in IE or Firefox. Does anyone has an idea about this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: standard example with a black background works fine for me in `Version 50.0.2661.75 m (64-bit)` -- more you can share?

Comment: Script source is https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js. It is embedded in a bootstrap jumbotron div and the chart itself is being built dynamically in a C# code behind and appended to an <asp:Literal> control. The issue was occurring even when I had a static example similar to Google's own tutorial.